# How is the interjection "Nanu" used?

Tags: dictionary

In what way is "Nanu" used actually? I'm just confused about it and I would appreciate it if you could help 
Thank you in advance

Comment: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nanu https://www.dwds.de/wb/nanu

Comment: The question is a bit suboptimal as it does not really demonstrate previous efforts to solve the question by other means. However, aside from that I find the question fully legitimate as e.g. the brief defintion in Duden ("Ausruf der Verwunderung") does not provide enough context for getting a good feeling for how to use the expression. Therefore I vote for reopening the question.

Answer (score 4):

*Nanu* is used to express astonishment/surprise mixed with an appeal for explanation.

You will find *nanu* hardly in normal everyday language today. It seems to have come out of use and sounds, if used, a bit outdated or perhaps even purposefully ironic. It continues however to be used in written texts presenting everyday dialogues, e.g. in novels.

Here are use cases:

> "Nanu, du bist ja noch hier?" said the wife who had seen her husband leave for work, as after half an hour she found him sitting on the front lawn seemingly doing nothing.
>
> "Nanu? Ich hatte sie doch vor fünf Minuten hier hingelegt?" said Paul staring at the empty lid of the grand piano, in search of his keys.

There are other interjections expressing emotions which - the interjections - are not any more in use:

- Potzblitz (stark surprise)
- Donnerwetter (same)
- Ei der Daus! (same)

Still in use, sometimes, although also sounding a bit manieristic (or literary):

- Herrje! (mild shock, about an unpleasant surprise)

In everyday use, at least in southern Germany:

- Oh Gott oh Gott! (or: ogottogott!) (desperation)

A dialectal example from the catholic South:

- Jeesesmariaondjoseph! (utter shock)

Another southern dialect:

- Zefix! (anger; short for "Kruzifix")

Comment: I'm trying to find common expressions used in my region. All I found for 'du bist noch da?' is '_ach / wie / wie jetzt_, or for a declarative sentence '_Sag bloß, du bist noch da!'_ But there are more than those: _Holla (die Waldfee)! / Ich werd' verrückt! / Man glaubt es nicht / Ich werd' zum Elch / Nun schau sich das einer an / Jetzt brat mir einer 'n Storch! / Ick fress'n Besen!_ and many many others, most of them outdated, unfortunately.

Comment: @RalfJoerres  Wie ich das lese, fällt mir jetzt noch *Sapperlot!* ein (veraltet). Dialektal und zeitgenössisch in Gebrauch aber: *Jetzetle!*. Sehr gebräuchlich sogar: *Hoi!*